# TURN Socket connection failed

Tags: iphone, openfire, xmppframework

I'm always getting TURN Connection failed. This is the code I'm using

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   XMPPJID *jid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:chatWithUser resource:@"Smack"];
   [TURNSocket setProxyCandidates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:chatWithUser, nil]];
   TURNSocket *turnSocket = [[TURNSocket alloc] initWithStream:[self xmppStream] toJID:jid];
   [turnSockets addObject:turnSocket];
   [turnSocket startWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
 }

 - (void)turnSocket:(TURNSocket *)sender didSucceed:(GCDAsyncSocket *)socket {
       NSLog(@"TURN Connection succeeded!");
       NSLog(@"You now have a socket that you can use to send/receive data to/from the other person.");
      [turnSockets removeObject:sender];
   }
  - (void)turnSocketDidFail:(TURNSocket *)sender {
      NSLog(@"TURN Connection failed!");
      [turnSockets removeObject:sender];
   }
```

Comment: The same is happening with me. Did you resolve your issue?